# MySQL query with COUNT() to return records where field equals COUNT value

Tags: mysql

I have the following query which works fine:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM attendance, cohort 
WHERE 
attendance.cohort_fk = cohort.cohort_pk 
AND 
attendance.cohort_fk = '$cohort' 
AND 
YEAR(attendance.attended) = '$year'
GROUP BY attendance.person_id ASC
```

In the table cohort, there is an int column 'attendance_pass'.  Now I want to have another query similar to above that only returns records where `COUNT(*) FROM attendance` equals cohort.attendance_pass. Eg.

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM attendance, cohort 
WHERE 
attendance.cohort_fk = cohort.cohort_pk 
AND 
attendance.cohort_fk = '$cohort' 
AND 
YEAR(attendance.attended) = '$year'
AND 
COUNT() = cohort.attendance_pass
GROUP BY attendance.person_id ASC
```

How can I modify this second query to get just those records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `HAVING`

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) FROM attendance, cohort 
WHERE 
attendance.cohort_fk = cohort.cohort_pk 
AND 
attendance.cohort_fk = '$cohort' 
AND 
YEAR(attendance.attended) = '$year'

GROUP BY attendance.person_id ASC

HAVING COUNT(*) = cohort.attendance_pass
```

Answer (score 1):

the aggregation functions must be in an having clause, not in the where clause.

By the way, you can use the alias.

And I don't think you can GROUP BY asc, you certainly mean a GROUP BY then an ORDER BY ... ASC

```
select *, count(*) as cnt from attendance
-- etc.

where
--etc.
having cnt = cohort.attendance_pass
GROUP BY attendance.person_id
ORDER BY attendance.person_id ASC
```

Comment: I had a problem with 'as cnt' returning "Unknown column 'attendance.cohort_fk' in 'where clause'"....